# Insert jQuery and Twitter PHP code into WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hi I am new to this so please bear with me. I have a free theme which is in html, it has an element on it that controls a twitter. I would like to add this look and feel to my wordpress blog on the footer. I have inserted the following code:

**in functions.php**
!! wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes_tweet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.tweet.js', array('jquery'));

**in the footer.php**

```
<div class="twitter-head">
    <h1>Twitter</h1>
    <a class="readmore tw" href="#">Follow Me</a>
</div>
<div class="tweet"></div>
```

and I have the actual jquery.tweet.js file in the js directory

The only thing that displays on the footer is TWITTER & follow me

it seems i still need some code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ok delete all that from you HTML , Then add this to the head :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tweet.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#tweet").tweet({ user: "peteog" });
        });
    </script>
```

changing the script src to your js directory and the username to your twitter username .

then add this to the footer :

```
<div id="tweet"></div>
```